# Kinect v2 sample code has undefined C++ headers

Tags: c++, header, undefined, kinect

I have installed version 2 of Kinect that comes with an integrated developer's toolkit. Problem is that when I load the sample face tracking project (Face Basics D2D), a majority of C++'s own headers like windows.h, string library, strsafe etc come out to be undefined (although all of Kinect's own headers and libraries appear OK). Can you tell me ***exactly*** how I am supposed to run that code? What are the steps?

I would be really grateful for your help.

Thanks in advance.

P.S if i write a program myself, then those headers appear defined- completely normal.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I finally found the answer:
Kinect v2 is ONLY compatible with visual studio 2013. kinect v1 is compatible with 2010.
Also if anyone wants to interface it with Matlab, you have to know that the support package available at
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40445-image-acquisition-toolbox-support-package-for-kinect-for-windows-runtime
is only for v1 of kinect. If you use it with v2, it will detect Kinect as an adaptor but will not recognize its depth and color sensor device IDs. v2 of Kinect is fairly new, and does not have its Matlab interface yet.